# Accessing keyboard settings in MacOS via Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, macos, nsuserdefaults

So here's what I'm trying to do:

I want to build a small application that places an icon in my top bar in MacOS. When clicking this icon, it should switch the setting "System Preferences > Keyboard > Use keys F1, F2, ... as standard function keys". So it basically works like [Caffeine](https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/caffeine/id411246225?mt=12) just for a different setting.

This is my current code (which is still in the test phase):

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    func test() {
        let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().dictionaryRepresentation()

        for value in defaults.keys {
            print(value + " - " + String(defaults[value]))
        }

    }

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
        test()
    }
}
```

The idea so far is to get the NSUserDefaults and get an overview of all they keys and the values stored in it. And here's my problem: How do I know which key I need to access the setting I want? I couldn't find any keys containing "keyboard" (I was expecting to see keys like `"com.apple.keyboard.*"`).
I haven't found any documentation covering the range of possible keys to access certain settings.

If anyone could help me out I'd really appreciate it!

Thanks and have a good day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, ironically I found it out just minutes after posting the question, but maybe this can help people to find other keys to access certain settings.

So first, the key I was looking for was `"com.apple.keyboard.fnState"`.

Now here's how you can find keys you're looking for:

Before accessing the NSUserDefaults make sure to change the setting you try to manipulate at least once. This way you guarantee that an entry for this setting will be written to NSUserDefaults. And that's exactly why I wasn't able to find the key, because I never touched this setting (which could be seen as stupid considering what I'm trying to achieve, but that's up to you...).

On a side note: I still think it's pretty sad that Apple has no documentation whatsoever covering this topic.

Hope this helps others!